# Windows 10 downgrade option missing, have windows.old directory

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, downgrade

In upgrade&security->reccovery, I don't have option to revert back to windows 8.1, but I do have windows.old directory and its contents.

My question is is there anything I can do at this point except formatting the HDD and reinstalling 8.1 again from scratch?

Comment: No; there is not

Comment: You only get that option in an adminstrator account. Are you logged on as a standard user?

Comment: @DavidMarshall I'm logged in as an administrator.

Comment: @Ramhound Why don't you post that as an answer??

Comment: Why is this question graded -2 (now -1 after I upvoted it)? It is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @David Balažic I guess people can't be bothered to actually read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it depends on what folders are in **Windows.old**.  You can boot from a install DVD/USB and repair and command prompt.  From there you need to (for safety/fall back reasons)

```
ren "c:\Program Files" "c:\Program Files.10"
ren "c:\Program Files (x86)" "c:\Program Files (x86).10"
ren "c:\Windows" "c:\Windows.10"
ren "c:\users" "c:\users.10"  (if users if present under windows.old)
ren "c:\ProgramData"  "c:\ProgramData.10"  (if present)
cd \windows.old
move *.* ..
```

This may or may not work for you, but I did it.  If it fails you can just move the folders back to windows.old and re-rename the folders.

Comment: Interesting way of looking at things! I'll definitely give it a try. I do have Program Files both 64bit and 32 bit, Recovery, Users, Windows and Program Data directories saved in Windows.old

Comment: @AndrejaKo   Ren ProgramData  ProgramData.10  Also

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from Windows 7 to 10, my PC immediately had problems (bluescreen after a minute after login, each time).

The "Go back" option in the *Settings* would not work (or even be present sometimes, I tried *safe mode*).

I discovered, that the `Go back to the previous build` in the boot menu does the same thing (except that it actually works). It is described in some articles, like this one: [How to Go Back to the Previous Windows from Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4097-windows-10-go-back-previous-windows.html)

In the boot menu select *Troubleshoot* / *Advanced options* / *Go back to the previous build*.

(see [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-advanced-startup-options-boot-windows-10-a.html) about how to get to the boot menu if you're not seeing it)

Comment: That's quite interesting. I didn't have the go back option in the boot menu.